# Issues with app routing for multi language site

Tags: next.js, url-routing

I'm rather new to nextjs, and I'm trying it out. At this moment I'm kind of stuck on routing and internacionalization (multi language). My question is as follows..

Imagine I want website in 2 languages English and French. The default is English. So when the user goes to home page => [www.site.com](http://www.site.com) it shows in English if the language which his browser is in is not supported. And if he navigates to contact it is then [www.site.com/contact](http://www.site.com/contact) | [www.site.com/about](http://www.site.com/about) and so on.

If a users language is French or he sets to french, then it should be like [www.site.com/fr](http://www.site.com/fr) | [www.site.com/fr/contact](http://www.site.com/fr/contact) | [www.site.com/fr/about](http://www.site.com/fr/about) and so on.

How do I achieve that?

I've read several blogs and there are different approaches etc... one that I understood from official documentation.

1. I have to create a middleware.ts and there put something like this:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { match } from '@formatjs/intl-localematcher'
import Negotiator from 'negotiator'
 

let headers = { 'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5' }
let languages = new Negotiator({ headers }).languages()
let locales = ['en', 'fr']
let defaultLocale = 'en'
 

// Get the preferred locale, similar to above or using a library
function getLocale(request: any): string { 
    return match(languages, locales, defaultLocale) // -> 'en-US'
 }
 
export function middleware(request: any) {
  // Check if there is any supported locale in the pathname
  const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname
  const pathnameIsMissingLocale = locales.every(
    (locale) => !pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) && pathname !== `/${locale}`
  )
 
  // Redirect if there is no locale
  if (pathnameIsMissingLocale) {
    const locale = getLocale(request)
 
    // e.g. incoming request is /products
    // The new URL is now /en-US/products
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL(`/${locale}/${pathname}`, request.url)
    )
  }
}
 
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    // Skip all internal paths (_next)
    '/((?!_next).*)',
    // Optional: only run on root (/) URL
    // '/'
  ],
}
```

And the file hierarchy should be like this:
src/app/[lang]/...

But this does not work well properly :(
Any idea, what am I doing wrong? (Im using the final version if next.js and app routing)

As I've described above, I've tried to code and create a proper folder structure, but it does not work...